# Compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(in\omega t-\gamma^2 t^2)dt$

Tags: integration

> How to compute the following integral?
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(in\omega t-\gamma^2 t^2)dt$$

Please help me.

Comment: Try to complete the square.

Comment: Would you mind adding context, the background of this question, what you know about these kind of integrals etc etc

Comment: denotes $i$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: there is a solution containing the error function